# MySQL query construction

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query problem. I have a table of agents that do things. I keep track of the things they do in an events table. I want to keep my agents busy but not too busy, so I need a query that will return me a group of agents that have done no more that 10 events in the past 10 minutes and no more than 400 events in the past 24 hours. And from this pool of available agents I can choose one to give something to do

So my agent table looks something like:

```
Agent table
AgentID.       AgentName
1                    Bob
2                    Sue

Event Table

Event ID.     Agent ID.    Event Timestamp
1                  2        1319525462
2                  1        1319525462
3                  2        1319525462
```

Obviously these tables are just to give the form of the db. What I need generally and have not been able to figure out is how to select a group of agents from a join that returns a group of agents that have done no more than 10 events in the past 10 min and no more than 400 events in the past 24 hours. My actual tables are more complex, but I am just looking for a general principle on how to structure a query that would return the desired result. Thanks ahead of time for the help!

**UPDATE
building on Benoit's answere I came up with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM campaign_agents 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT count(event_index) myevents, field_event_agent_value FROM new_event WHERE field_event_time_value BETWEEN 1320206138 AND 1320292538 GROUP BY field_event_agent_value ) last_24_hours 
ON last_24_hours.field_event_agent_value = campaign_agents.username 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT count(event_index) myevents, field_event_agent_value FROM new_event WHERE field_event_time_value BETWEEN 1320291938 AND 1320292538 GROUP BY field_event_agent_value ) last_10_mins 
ON last_10_mins.field_event_agent_value = campaign_agents.username 
WHERE last_24_hours.myevents < 550 AND last_10_mins.myevents < 10
```

But it doesn't get the agents in the campaign_agents table who haven't done anything yet and are therefore not in the events table. Shouldn't a LEFT OUTER JOIN include everything in the first table, campaign_agents, even if there are no matches to the second table? Do I need to put and OR statement after the where to somehow get them included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT agent.agentid
  FROM agent
 INNER JOIN (SELECT count(eventid) events, agentid
               FROM event
              WHERE timestamp BETWEEN /* (now - 24 hours) */ AND /* now */ -- adapt this
              GROUP BY agentid
            ) last_24_hours
    ON last_24_hours.agentid = agent.agentid
 INNER JOIN (SELECT count(eventid) events, agentid
               FROM event
              WHERE timestamp BETWEEN /* (now - 10 minutes) */ AND /* now */ -- adapt this
              GROUP BY agentid
            ) last_10_mins
    ON last_10_mins.agentid = agent.agentid
WHERE last_24_hours.events < 400
  AND last_10_mins.events < 10
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and report back!

Comment: Thank you very much for the query. I am learning more just from modifying it. I used the query you provided as the basis of a new query for my script and it worked well for awhile and then stopped. I think the problem might be is that the agent list is long and, especially at the beginning of the campaign not all agents have events attributed to them. How would I get the agents that have not done anything yet? I have tried adding them as "test" events to the event table to see if they would be picked up that way but no luck so far.